# Copy to Clipboard and render as Link in Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to copy the content from div element and trying to paste it in the excel sheet.

So for a sample, I have put the `href` tag in the div element and copied the `href` to the clipboard using `document.execCommand("copy")` and it has copied successfully but when I am trying to paste it in the excel sheet, it is directly echoing as the HTML text instead of convert to a link.

I have tried to copy the link with the help of mouse and pasted it in the excel, then it is working perfectly. Here is the sample script I used:

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/bevexafiva/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to reconsider the function logic. You dont really need a temp div outside of the screen to copy to clipboard. Here is what you could do.

The paste should work as a link in Excel as your expecting.

```js
var copyBtn = $("#copy-btn");

function copyToClipboard() {
  var element = document.getElementById("copy-me");
  if (!element) {
    return;
  }

  var range;

  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(element);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var selectedContent = window.getSelection();

    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(element);
    selectedContent.removeAllRanges();
    selectedContent.addRange(range);
  }
  document.execCommand("copy", false, null);

}

copyBtn.on('click', copyToClipboard);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="Element To Be Copied" id="copy-me">
  <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>
<button id="copy-btn">Copy</button>
<div>
  <textArea></textArea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sreekanth . In the place I am using it, I need to create a temp div so that, it will not display [just a requirement]. Anyways thanks once again